# How to test that a file is left unchanged?

Tags: unit-testing, language-agnostic

I'm testing a function that *may* modify a file. How do i test that it is unchanged in the cases where I want it to?

- I don't want to check the content, because the file may have been overwritten with the same content, changing the modification time.
- I can't really check the modification time, either. Since I like tests to be self-contained, the original file would be written just before the (non-)modification test, rendering the modification time unreliable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use DI to mock your filewriter. This way you do not need the file at all, only check if the write function is called and you know if the file was modified.

Comment: By DI I assume you mean dependency injection?

Comment: Yes, DI is dependency injection.

Answer (score 1):

I would split the function into two separate functions; the first decides whether the modification should be made, the second makes the notification. The second is only called if necessary. In pretend language:

```
function bool IsModificationRequired()
{
    // return true or false based on your actual code
}

function void WriteFile()
{
    new File().Write("file");
}

function void WriteIfModified()
{
    if (IsModificationRequired())
        WriteFile();

}
```

And test

```
Assert.IsTrue(IsModificationRequired());
```

Answer (score 0):

Well assuming you are using a text file and reasonable size. Just hash the file content, if before modify and after modidfy hashcode is same then - it means the file content is not changed.

Here is the link to Algorithim Design Manual - Steve Skiena  (Google Book Result)
Section 3.8 
[How can i convicne you that a file isn't changed ?](http://books.google.com/books?id=7XUSn0IKQEgC&lpg=PA92&ots=z7bIKTIM2f&dq=skiena%20compare%20the%20few%20documents%20sharing%20the%20exact%20hash%20code%20with%20little&pg=PA93#v=onepage&q=skiena%20compare%20the%20few%20documents%20sharing%20the%20exact%20hash%20code%20with%20little&f=false)